# Python Toolbox issue

Tags: python

I am working on creating a python toolbox to solve for WiFi signal properties based on various inputs, and for the end result I would like to have the output in the form of a raster. I need this raster to take on an equation value (FSPL) for each cell, based on a cost raster (distance raster) and numerical inputs (frequency type in GHz and feet-meter conversion coefficient). Below is the code that I have attempted, but I get an error reading:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 108, in execute
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.
Failed to execute (FSPL).
```

Here is the code below (with line 108 marked with writing in the code itself near the bottom):

```
import arcpy
import math

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox Label Property"
        self.alias = "Toolbox Alias Property"

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [FSPL, WAP_Buffer]


class FSPL(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Free Space Path Loss"
        self.description = "This python script tool will create Free Space Path Loss to determine the dB range output from the WAPs."
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""

        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Wireless Access Points",
        name="wireless_pts",
        datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Network Frequency Type",
        name="network_freq",
        datatype="String",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
        param1.filter.type="ValueList"
        param1.filter.list = ["2.4 GHz", "5 GHz"]

        param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Distance Raster",
        name="dist_rast",
        datatype="GPRasterLayer",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")

        param3 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Distance Raster Units",
        name="units",
        datatype="String",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
        param3.filter.type="ValueList"
        param3.filter.list = ["Feet", "Meters"]

        param4 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Output Raster",
        name="output_rast",
        datatype="GPRasterLayer",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Output")

        return [param0, param1, param2, param3, param4]

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""

        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""

        #Get inputs
        wireless_pts = parameters[0].valueAsText
        network_freq = parameters[1].valueAsText
        dist_rast = parameters[2].valueAsText
        units = parameters[3].valueAsText
        output_rast = parameters[4].valueAsText

        shapeFieldName = arcpy.Describe(wireless_pts).shapeFieldName

        #Create expression

        if network_freq == "2.4 GHz":
            hertz=2400000000
        else:
            hertz=5000000000

        if units == "Feet":
            distmod=0.3048
        else:
            distmod=1

        #equation

LINE 108 fspl= (4 * math.pi * distmod * dist_rast * hertz)/(2.99792458 * (10**8))
        output_rast = fspl



        return
```

I am fairly new to using python and there could be something very basic that I am not grasping. This all seemed a little to easy for someone without much python experience to produce, and so I am skeptical that I am forgetting something big. If anyone has any ideas on how I can implement what I want to produce I would be very happy to hear them.

Comment: Have you try printing all variable before line 108?

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156016/how-to-build-a-raster-populated-with-an-equation-in-a-python-toolbox

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem lies in this line:

`dist_rast = parameters[2].valueAsText`

If it's doing what I think it is it's returning a `string` object that can't be multiplied by a float (which you're trying to do with `math.pi`, possibly `distmod`)

Instead, convert this to a float as well and try again.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 89, in execute
ValueError: could not convert string to float: CostDist_WiFi1

Failed to execute (FSPL).

Comment: CostDist_WiFi1 is a raster, does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: I don't know what your value of `dist_rast` is @CameronSloan . I presumed it was a value like `0.112` which would convert with `float("0.112")`. But if it's a string like `"Not found"` then it obviously wont convert to float. Print your variable and see if it's as expected

Comment: @CameronSloan - If I helped you solve your problem please upvote/accept my answer.

Comment: Still looking into it, I will accept your answer if it helped once I get to the root of it.